# How to remove facebook comment box on PAGES & only show on POSTS?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, comments

I'm using Wordpress for my website. I did add Facebook comment box to my website successfully with qualified user id and app id.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/vi_VN/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=165596420562496";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

...but I don't know how to remove/disable/delete/cancel facebook comment box on my PAGES and *only show* it on my POSTS. I've been struggling and sad many days without the solution to this (because I'm really bad at coding new things). I'd be grateful to anyone helping me with this issue. Note: I've tried using many different plugins for this matter (since I know nothing) but not once has worked. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following code to your functions.php (child theme).

```
function facebook_comment_add_to_content( $content ) {

if( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
    $content .= "<div id='fb-root'></div>
                    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
                      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                      js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/vi_VN/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=165596420562496';
                      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script> <h1>Yhea men</h1>";
}

return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'facebook_comment_add_to_content');
```

Note: you can also use https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/facebook-comments-plugin/ in the settings tab you can enable 'Singular Posts'. Then the facebook comment section will not display on pages (other custom post types will show the facebook section).